# Getting a Hashtable from Gson

Tags: java, libgdx, gson

I have a .json file storing the value of a hashtable

{FISH:{class:java.lang.Integer,value:7},EGGS:{class:java.lang.Integer,value:6},CHICKEN:{class:java.lang.Integer,value:7}}

I save the table no problem:

```
private void saveInventory()
{
    Json json = new Json();
    file.writeString(json.prettyPrint(inventory.inv), false);
}
```

I am trying to load that table using Gson.

I have tried a couple of different ways based on several other questions on here. Each have given different errors, malformedJsonException,  currently have the below and it's giving me the error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected STRING but was BEGIN_OBJECT

```
private void loadInventory() {
    Json json = new Json();
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("bin/data.json"));
        JsonObject object = (JsonObject) new com.google.gson.JsonParser().parse(br);
        Set<Map.Entry<String, JsonElement>> set = object.entrySet();
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonElement>> iterator = set.iterator();

        Hashtable<Constants.FoodTypes, Integer> map = new Hashtable<Constants.FoodTypes, Integer>();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry = iterator.next();

            Constants.FoodTypes value = gson.fromJson(entry.getValue(), Constants.FoodTypes.class);
            Integer key = Integer.parseInt(entry.getKey());

            if (value != null) {
                map.put(value, key);
            }

        }

    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

What is a better way to load this back as a hashtable?

Comment: Why are you using `Hashtable`? You should probably be using `HashMap`.

Comment: Your code can be simplified (both idiomatic Java and Gson) + you're swapping value and key in your result map.

Comment: `Hashtable` has been obsolescent since 1998. 1998! How long have you been using Java, @Daniel Von Lincoln?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"{FISH:{class:java.lang.Integer,value:7},EGGS:{class:java.lang.Integer,value:6},CHICKEN:{class:java.lang.Integer,value:7}}"
is not a proper JSON object.
You could create the file (or string) by using Gson to generate it from a hashtable.

In this case, your json string should be

```
{
  "FISH": {
    "class": "java.lang.Integer",
    "value": 7
  },
  "EGGS": {
    "class": "java.lang.Integer",
    "value": 6
  },
  "CHICKEN": {
    "class": "java.lang.Integer",
    "value": 7
  }
}
```

Comment: All that it took was changing my save file from a json.prettyprint() to a gson.toJson() and there were still some kinks but that solved all my major problems. Thank you very much.